# how to detect colors from asset in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout

i have design like below.

[image: requirement]

i need to put number widget in the path above and change the color of number based on some logic

provided with path asset like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0M02.png) (it's too long to be shown here)

while thinking how to achieve this, it's impossible to draw path from scratch because it's too complex (is it?),, i think if there's a way to detect list of coordinates of color from path provided above would be helpful, or maybe any other suggestion to achieve this? thank you..

===== edit

the requirement is so similar with map in game development like this

[image]

i wonder how they could accurately put the number widget in such position. hardcoding x and y coordinate wouldn't work in terms of responsiveness i think

Comment: You can use this package might be helpful : https://pub.dev/packages/game_levels_scrolling_map

Comment: @khuntarpit the package works as expected, thanks